# Access data at memory address that is part of a struct

Tags: ghidra

### Problem

I have a struct of some type, say the DOS header at the beginning of a typical PE file:

```
/DOS/IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
pack(disabled)
Structure IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
   0   char[2]   2   e_magic   "Magic number"
   2   word   2   e_cblp   "Bytes of last page"
   4   word   2   e_cp   "Pages in file"
   6   word   2   e_crlc   "Relocations"
   8   word   2   e_cparhdr   "Size of header in paragraphs"
   10   word   2   e_minalloc   "Minimum extra paragraphs needed"
   12   word   2   e_maxalloc   "Maximum extra paragraphs needed"
   14   word   2   e_ss   "Initial (relative) SS value"
   16   word   2   e_sp   "Initial SP value"
   18   word   2   e_csum   "Checksum"
   20   word   2   e_ip   "Initial IP value"
   22   word   2   e_cs   "Initial (relative) CS value"
   24   word   2   e_lfarlc   "File address of relocation table"
   26   word   2   e_ovno   "Overlay number"
   28   word[4]   8   e_res[4]   "Reserved words"
   36   word   2   e_oemid   "OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)"
   38   word   2   e_oeminfo   "OEM information; e_oemid specific"
   40   word[10]   20   e_res2[10]   "Reserved words"
   60   dword   4   e_lfanew   "File address of new exe header"
   64   byte[64]   64   e_program   "Actual DOS program"
}
Size = 128   Actual Alignment = 1
```

at address `00400000` in memory that is initialized as part of the loader and has some fixed values. It's already defined as a struct in Ghidra, e.g. by some auto analysis.

[image]

Now I want to get the value of e.g. `e_cp`, the "Pages in file", in this case `3`, ideally as a proper Ghidra datatype in case that is a pointer, address or some more complex datatype. Ideally I want to access it by the name "e_cp" and not by hardcoding the offset.

### Attempts

`getDataAt(currentProgram.imageBase + 4)`, returns `null`,
`etDataContaining(currentProgram.imageBase + 4)` returns a DataDB object for the entire `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` struct.

How can I get the actual value in memory at a known address, that is part of a struct?

Comment: >>> getDataContaining(currentProgram.imageBase).getComponentAt(4)
dw 3h  is that what you need ?

Comment: yes, this was pretty much what I needed, and had initially tried to find on the RE SE, but didn't find an existing question. In the process of writing up the question I had found the solution myself and posted the question and a self answer as is encouraged https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I read your self answer but wasn't sure what was the required end result ?  what you were looking for so commented and answered  btw .....dat.getAllStructures() will return an iterator you can cast any data as any structure using next()  some thing like windbg (nt!_EPROCESS *) 0x1234

Comment: The core of the answer is `.getComponentAt`. it took me a while to realize that the method for the datatype and the data object are different.

Comment: I am not sure how `dat.getAllStructures()` would have helped me though. It seems easier to get the datatype of the data by using `getDataContaining(currentProgram.imageBase).dataType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the value of e.g. e_cp, the "Pages in file", in this case 3, ideally as a proper Ghidra datatype in case that is a pointer, address or some more complex datatype

You have to access a member of a struct (or an array) with the `getComponent` method, e.g. in Kotlin code( easily changed to Python or Java):

```
var struct: DataDB = getDataAt(currentProgram.imageBase)
struct.getComponent(2)
```

this will return the value for the third (zero indexing) component of the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` struct: `dw 3h`

> Ideally I want to access it by the name "e_cp" and not by hardcoding the offset.

There seems to be no direct way to access a struct my member name. The information about the member names, types and sizes is contained in `struct.dataType` if this is cast to `Structure` you can use `getComponent` (different method than above!):

```
import ghidra.program.model.data.Structure
var struct: Data = getDataAt(currentProgram.imageBase)
var structType: Structure = struct.dataType as Structure
structType.getComponent(2)
```

will result in a `DataTypeComponent` object rendered as:
`2  4  word  2  e_cp  "Pages in file"`.

This object has an attribute `fieldName` that contains the name "e_cp" of this member.
You can use the `structType.components` attribute to find the field with your desired name, and then get the `.ordinal` attribute of the `DataTypeComponent` object to get the correct index to pass to `struct.getComponent`

For convenience and only in Kotlin you can define an [Extension Method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html)

```
operator fun Data.get(name: String): Data? {
    if (this.dataType is Structure){
        val s = (this.dataType as Structure)
        val idx = s.components.firstOrNull { it.fieldName == name }?.ordinal
        return idx?.let(this::getComponent)
    }
    return null
}
```

that allows `Data` objects to be indexed with a string, which will search the components for a field matching the passed string, and return the appropriate component:

```
In [1]: getDataAt(currentProgram.imageBase)["e_cp"]
Out[1]: dw 3h
```

Answer (score 2):

As i commented is this what you are looking for ?

```
>>> base = getDataContaining(currentProgram.imageBase)
>>> base
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER 
>>> for i in range (0,base.length,1):
...     print ( base.baseDataType.getComponentAt(i).toString() , base.getComponentAt(i))
... 
(u'  0  0  char[2]  2  e_magic  "Magic number"', char[2] "MZ")
(u'  0  0  char[2]  2  e_magic  "Magic number"', char[2] "MZ")
(u'  1  2  word  2  e_cblp  "Bytes of last page"', dw 90h)
(u'  1  2  word  2  e_cblp  "Bytes of last page"', dw 90h)
(u'  2  4  word  2  e_cp  "Pages in file"', dw 3h)
(u'  2  4  word  2  e_cp  "Pages in file"', dw 3h)
(u'  3  6  word  2  e_crlc  "Relocations"', dw 0h)
(u'  3  6  word  2  e_crlc  "Relocations"', dw 0h)
(u'  4  8  word  2  e_cparhdr  "Size of header in paragraphs"', dw 4h)
(u'  4  8  word  2  e_cparhdr  "Size of header in paragraphs"', dw 4h)
(u'  5  10  word  2  e_minalloc  "Minimum extra paragraphs needed"', dw 0h)
(u'  5  10  word  2  e_minalloc  "Minimum extra paragraphs needed"', dw 0h)
(u'  6  12  word  2  e_maxalloc  "Maximum extra paragraphs needed"', dw FFFFh)
(u'  6  12  word  2  e_maxalloc  "Maximum extra paragraphs needed"', dw FFFFh)
(u'  7  14  word  2  e_ss  "Initial (relative) SS value"', dw 0h)
(u'  7  14  word  2  e_ss  "Initial (relative) SS value"', dw 0h)
(u'  8  16  word  2  e_sp  "Initial SP value"', dw B8h)
(u'  8  16  word  2  e_sp  "Initial SP value"', dw B8h)
(u'  9  18  word  2  e_csum  "Checksum"', dw 0h)
(u'  9  18  word  2  e_csum  "Checksum"', dw 0h)
(u'  10  20  word  2  e_ip  "Initial IP value"', dw 0h)
(u'  10  20  word  2  e_ip  "Initial IP value"', dw 0h)
(u'  11  22  word  2  e_cs  "Initial (relative) CS value"', dw 0h)
(u'  11  22  word  2  e_cs  "Initial (relative) CS value"', dw 0h)
(u'  12  24  word  2  e_lfarlc  "File address of relocation table"', dw 40h)
(u'  12  24  word  2  e_lfarlc  "File address of relocation table"', dw 40h)
(u'  13  26  word  2  e_ovno  "Overlay number"', dw 0h)
(u'  13  26  word  2  e_ovno  "Overlay number"', dw 0h)
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  14  28  word[4]  8  e_res[4]  "Reserved words"', dw[4] )
(u'  15  36  word  2  e_oemid  "OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)"', dw 0h)
(u'  15  36  word  2  e_oemid  "OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)"', dw 0h)
(u'  16  38  word  2  e_oeminfo  "OEM information; e_oemid specific"', dw 0h)
(u'  16  38  word  2  e_oeminfo  "OEM information; e_oemid specific"', dw 0h)
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  17  40  word[10]  20  e_res2[10]  "Reserved words"', dw[10] )
(u'  18  60  dword  4  e_lfanew  "File address of new exe header"', ddw 108h)
(u'  18  60  dword  4  e_lfanew  "File address of new exe header"', ddw 108h)
(u'  18  60  dword  4  e_lfanew  "File address of new exe header"', ddw 108h)
(u'  18  60  dword  4  e_lfanew  "File address of new exe header"', ddw 108h)
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
(u'  19  64  byte[64]  64  e_program  "Actual DOS program"', db[64] )
```